# How to get the maximum value of three stacked numpy arrays (representing images) to get the intersection area?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have three images in  three numpy arrays `a,c,s`. The values are between [0,0.99] (the probabilities). The following shows the vertical arrangement of images.

[image]

I stacked them by this command `x=np.dstack([a,c,s])` and the shape becomes (256, 256, 3), the following image is obtained:

[image]

I wanted to get the maximum value among three stacked arrays, to maximum intersection area of images, for example for each point, we have three values:

```
print x[200,100,:]
out: [0.99662614 0.98577976 0.99949038]
```

after getting `argmax`, I am getting the following output:

```
maxIndex= np.argmax(x, axis=2)
print np.shape(maxIndex)
plt.imshow(maxIndex)
plt.show()
```

[image]

which is not what I want. Could you please guide me how to get the maximum value of three values in a way that I can get maximum intersection area of three?

Comment: [No "_thanks"_ please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What do you want? I don't understand. There is only one way to "get the maximum value of three values". Try to make the question clear (put effort into writing the question).

Comment: @user202729 I want to get the largest intersection area of three arrays. However, I can not get by argmax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you forgot to use `argmax` indices to actually get the maximum values along `axis=2`:

```
rr, cc = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x.shape[0]),
                     np.arange(x.shape[1]),
                     indexing='ij',
                     sparse=True)
x_max = x[rr, cc, maxIndex]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, This  is what I wanted to do.